Error after extending UEFI partition
I attempted to increase the UEFI partition size from 100 MB to 1 GB. To do this, I created a new partition (P4) with the desired size and copied the files from the original 100 MB partition to it. I have a dual-boot setup with Windows and Ubuntu. After booting into Ubuntu, I deleted the old 100 MB partition (P1). However, this caused the Windows boot process to fail because it was still referencing the deleted partition (P1).
I tried resolving the issue from Ubuntu, but after rebooting, I encountered error code 0xc0000001, as shown in the attached image. Now, neither Windows nor Ubuntu will boot. How can I fix this?


What did you do to "tr(y) resolving the issue from Ubuntu"? Please list the precise steps you took. Have you booted from a Windows disk and run a repair? Or have you accessed Safe Mode and attempted to run boot repair or recovery? Can you also share what motivated you to try to expand your UEFI partition?

Please also tell us how you created the new partition, what specific steps you took, what flags or settings you applied, etc. Perhaps review this question as well: https://superuser.com/questions/1736092/moving-a-suspected-grub-partition-safety-when-resizing-partitions

What instructions did you follow? If you manually created the partition and manually copied the files that isn't going to work. Why were you increasing the size?

The issue is likely the BCD Store, which can be corrected from Linux via ms-sys (from WinRE it would be bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /rebuildbcd, however it needs to be verified that won't overwrite GRUB with EFI). Max EFI partition size that would ever be needed is 850MB when dual booting (that's only because at least one distro wants an EFI partition size of ~750MB, but doesn't stipulate if it actually needs 750MB, so I always say to sum what Windows wants [100MB] with that). EFI partition needs to be at the front of the disk or inconveniences will occur with resizing other partitions.

@JW0914: Last I checked ms-sys does not correct the BCD store; it only has the ability to write a BIOS MBR/VBR. I don't really trust bootrec, though; would generally suggest the newer bcdboot (it will install both the BCD and the static files that go in that partition).

@grawity I misread one of your comments about ms-sys here -there is a Linux program that writes the BCD Store since it had to be done from Linux when dual-booting due to bootrec overwriting GRUB (I don't have a way to test what occurs w/ GPT & EFI at the moment, as you mentioned it may only occur w/ BIOS and MBR). AFAIK bootrec is the correct front end program to use in WinRE for boot issues and it uses bcdboot on the backend AFAIK

@JW0914: bootrec /fixmbr writes boot code to the MBR. The OP is UEFI booting and this type of booting does not use the code in the MBR to boot any operating system.

@DavidAnderson I understand why folks see the mbr portion of that command and think it applies to an MBR partition table, it doesn't - AFAIK it's applicable to both MBR and GPT partition tables (Microsoft explains in one of their man pages, as I had the same opinion years ago before stumbling upon it, and while I can't find it at the moment, they do briefly touch on it in a roundabout way here)

I did not say the command has anything to do with the MBR table. The table remains unchanged. The bootrec /fixmbr command writes boot code to the MBR. This code is not used when UEFI booting any operating system. The command does this regardless of whether the drive using a MBR partition table, a GUID partition table (GPT) or the hybrid form where both are used. It will do this even if there is no partition table.
